# Binary To Decimal Recursion - without global variable

Tags: c++, recursion

i am learning recursion in C++ and as practice i was trying to write binary to decimal converter with recursive function. In following code converter is working as it should:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int sum = 0;

int DecimalConversion (int power, int number){      
    int bit;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    bit = number % 10;
    sum = sum + bit * pow(2, power);
    number /= 10;
    power++;

    DecimalConversion(power, number);
    return sum;

    //return bit * pow(2, power) + DecimalConversion(power, number);
}

int main(){
    int power = 0;
    int number = 0;

    cout <<  "Enter binary number: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Number is: " << DecimalConversion(power, number);

    system("PAUSE >> NULL");
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to return value from `DecimalCoonversion` function by not using global variable? Can someone explain how, I tried next line of code but it does not work  correctly:

```
return bit * pow(2, power) + DecimalConversion(power, number);
```

Can anyone explain where i am making mistake using previous line of code?
Thank You in advance

Comment: Hint: you're supposed to use the return value of the recursive call to `DecimalConversion`.

Comment: Mmm no ... ` The variable 'sum' is being used without being initialized.` I have exception thrown, and that is reason i used global variable  - because i can not use `int sum=0;` inside function

Comment: @hajrovica I misread it first time, sorry. See my answer for an updated response.

Comment: @hajrovica The line you've commented out works well for me. What was the problem with it? (You don't need the `sum` varuable at all.)

Comment: Yes line i commented out works but it doe not calculate right values

Comment: Could you please accept an answer if you're happy with it?

Answer (score 1):

This adds `sum` as a parameter to your function, but makes it default to `0` if you don't provide it explictly. Power is also defaulted to `0`, which saves you having to pass it into the function.

Since default parameters *must* be at the end of a function declarations and/or definitions parameter list, I had to move `power` across to achieve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int DecimalConversion (int number, int power = 0, int sum = 0) // changes here
{  
    if (number == 0)
    {
        return sum;
    }

    int bit = number % 10;
    sum = sum + bit * pow(2, power);
    number /= 10;
    power++;

    return DecimalConversion(number, power, sum); // changes here
}

int main(){
    int number = 0;

    cout <<  "Enter binary number: " << endl;
    cin >> number;
    cout << "Number is: " << DecimalConversion(number);

    system("PAUSE >> NULL");
    return 0;
}
```

Please note I didn't check this actually converts binary to decimal correctly, just that the recursion works.

You can call this function like so:

```
DecimalConversion(number);
```

Comment: Power can also be initialized to zero in parameter since OP did this in main.

Comment: Ok recursion works in this example  but thing is this does not return anything  - result of this call is 0. There should be `return sum;` in DecimalConversion function.  Also i need converter to calculate right values. So  i added `DecimalConversion(number, power, sum); return sum;` - this returns only first sum = 1 also tried to add `return sum + DecimalConversion(number, power, sum);` -  it does not  calculate right for entered binary value 111 it retuns 11 where it should be 7.  Any help on this get working?

Comment: When I run it, it returns 7 as expected. I've added the rest of the source for you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
int DecimalConversion(int power, int number){
    if (number == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return (number % 10)*pow(2, power) + dc(power+1, number/10);
}
```

or

```
int DecimalConversion(int power, int number){
    return number?(number % 10)*pow(2, power) + dc(power+1, number/10):0;
}
```

Comment: How is the second better? It's much harder to read and you gain nothing from using it over the first.

Comment: I agree. The number two is just a different interpretation of `if/else`. It doesn't make it "better".

Comment: @OMGtechy : only feeling, I know ... however the 'better' is removed